Multiplying Two asymmetric Laurent series
The following result $$\left(\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_i x^i\right)\left(\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} b_j x^j\right) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left( \sum_{\substack{j+i=k\\ i,j \ge 0}} a_i b_j\right) x^k $$ is well known. I was wondering if the following general identity also holds true

$$\left(\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_i x^{mi}\right)\left(\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} b_j x^{nj}\right) = \sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}\left( \sum_{\substack{nj+mi=k\\ i,j \ge 0 }} a_i b_j\right) x^k \tag{*} $$
where $m,n$ are non-zero integers and gcd$(|n|,|m|)=1$.

This came up when I was trying to answer this problem and realized that $$\left(\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{a_i}{x^{mi}}\right)\left(\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} b_j x^{j}\right) = \sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}\left( \sum_{\substack{j-mi=k\\ i,j \ge 0 }} a_i b_j\right) x^k $$
where $m>0$ is a natural number. Is the sum (*) correct? I am not sure how to give a proof for it, other than comparing the coefficients. Can it be generalized to product of three or more Laurent series? that is, $$\left(\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_i x^{mi}\right)\left(\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} b_j x^{nj}\right)\left(\sum_{l=0}^{\infty} c_l x^{pl}\right) = \sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}\left( \sum_{\substack{nj+mi+pl=k\\ i,j,l \ge 0 }} a_i b_j c_l\right) x^k \tag{**} $$
wher $i,j,l$ are integers in the sum, $m,n,p$ are non-zero integers, and gcd$(|m|,|n|,|p|)= \text{gcd}(\text{gcd}(|m|,|n|),|p|)=1$.
Addendum: As @Exodd has suggested, the gcd requriement is not needed as the sum of coefficients is then empty. However, in that case, I believe the sum can be simplified further as $$\left(\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_i x^{mi}\right)\left(\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} b_j x^{nj}\right) = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}\left( \sum_{\substack{nj+mi=d k\\ i,j \ge 0}} a_i b_j\right) x^{dk} $$
where $d=gcd(|n|,|m|)$.

the problem here is that the sum may be infinite, so in theory you cannot write it unless $m,n>0$

Consider these as formal series. @Exodd

no, no, the sum for the formal series is ok. The problem is the sum of the coefficients that could be a sum of an infinite number of terms..

@Exodd yes, that is true. For instance if we take $m=-1$ and $n=1$, then the coefficient of $x^0$ is $ \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_ib_i$. For now let's not worry about the convergence of these sums. I am more interested in the expression of these coefficients

the sums are correct whenever you can ensure that all sums of cofficients converge

Right @Exodd . So the $(*)$ and $(**)$ sum are correct? Any way to prove it ?

yes, and you don't even need the hypotheses about the gcd

we don't need it ? But it the gcd is not 1, then some terms might not exist. For instance if $n=m=2$, then coefficient of $x^1$ is zero.

it still holds. An empty sum is equal to 0 by convention

Aah I see. If you are willing to write a proof for $(*)$ I will accept it @Exodd .

Since you do not care about the convergence of the series to multiply, so we define the product
of formal Laurent series $\sum_{i\in\mathbb Z} a_i x^i$ and $\sum_{i\in\mathbb Z} b_i x^i$ as $\sum_{i\in\mathbb Z} c_i x^i$, provided for each $i\in\mathbb Z$ the double series $\sum_{j\in\mathbb Z} a_j b_{i-j}$ converges to $c_i$. Then for each case from the question we have to check that this product coincides with the product from the case. This indeed holds, provided the respective double serieses converge. But since for the given double series the order of its members can be not provided, I think a good decision will be to require the absolute convergence of the double series.
For instance, let us consider the case (**). I think since we wrote its left-hand side in the form $(\dots)(\dots)(\dots)$, we assume that the product of the series is associative. But in fact this condition can be too strong, so given formal Laurent series $P=\sum_{i\in\mathbb Z} p_i x^i$,
$Q=\sum_{i\in\mathbb Z} q_i x^i$, and $R=\sum_{i\in\mathbb Z} r_i x^i$, we can look for a product $(PQ)R$. For this we require first that for each $j\in\mathbb Z$ the double series $\sum_{i\in\mathbb Z} p_i q_{j-i}$ absolutely converges to some number $s_j$. Next we require that for each $k\in\mathbb Z$ the double series $\sum_{j\in\mathbb Z} s_j r_{k-j}$ absolutely converges to some number $t_k$, which is the coefficient at $x^k$ in the product $(PQ)R$. Then $$t_k=\sum_{j\in\mathbb Z}\left( \sum_{i\in\mathbb Z}p_j q_{i-j}\right) r_{k-j}=\sum_{j,i\in\mathbb Z}p_j q_{i-j} r_{k-j},$$
provided the latter sum absolutely converges. We can rearrange it as $$t_k=\sum_{i,j,l\in\mathbb Z\\i+j+l=k} p_i q_j r_l.$$
Now putting $P=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_i x^{mi}$,
$Q=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} b_j x^{nj}$, and $R=\sum_{l=0}^{\infty} c_l x^{pl}$
we see that for each $\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}$ we have $$t_k=\sum_{\substack{nj+mi+pl=k\\ i,j,l \ge 0 }} a_i b_j c_l.$$

how does this prove $(*)$ or the general result? @Alex

@Sam For instance, for the case $()$, let $k$ be any integer number. By the definition of the product, the coefficient $c_k$ at $x^k$ in the product series is equal to the sum of all $a_ib_j$ such that $mi+nj=k$, provided the sum (absolutely) converges. This is exactly the coefficient at $x^k$ at the right hand side of (). The other cases are similar.

aah I see, so does this also prove the product of three or more Laurent series $(**)$ ? @Alex

If you could provide a bit more explanation for (**) when gcd is not $1$, then I think that would be enough @Alex

@Sam I extended the answer.
